# Pulseaudio changing default source not applied to applications that were running before

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone

In Ubuntu 18.04, I am regularly switching between sound/mic on the Laptop and via a Headset. However I do not always want to do this via pavucontrol as it is tedious to do when some applications are running.

Therefore I came up with a script which uses various pactl commands to switch back and forth whenever required.

For mic/source I basically do the following steps

```
pactl list short source-outputs

-> for each item I perform
pactl move-source-output <stream> <newSource>

pactl set-default-source <newSource>
```

Applications which record audio at the moment are switched properly by the `move-source-output` command.

However the set-default-source sometimes does not take effect! To me it looks like pulseaudio somehow "remembers" which source an application did use before and it automatically selects that source again for a specific application. I.e. audacity uses the laptop-mic, a simple `arecord` uses the headset-mic, although default is set to "laptop" currently.

But I would like to do the switch fully, i.e. all applications should use the given source from now on until I do another switch.

Is there any way I can control this behavior in pulseaudio so it does not try to be smart and remember which source/source-output was selected before per application?

I also looked at files in /etc/pulse and ~/.pulse, but could not find anything that seems related there, maybe one of the default modules is causing this?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am running Ubuntu Bionic. However I found the answer myself just now, see below.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in the pulseaudio documentation at https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/DefaultDevice/

There is an option `restore_device` for module `module-stream-restore` which you can set to `false`, with the following in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` I get the desired behavior:

```
load-module module-stream-restore restore_device=false
```